# iOS NSBundle: dynamic loading bundle in Xcode7 error

Tags: ios, nsbundle

I have created a customized bundle with some extra Classes in it by Xcode7. I want to dynamic loading the bundle into my new Xcode project so that I can use those extra classes. However, I encounter the loading Error:**The bundle “CustomGreeter” couldn’t be loaded because it doesn’t contain a version for the current architecture**." Does anyone have any idea about this? The code is as following:

```
NSString *bundlePath = @"/Users/LAL/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomGreeter-eclhcyzsdwgsynhbccujsftunknl/Build/Products/Debug/CustomGreeter.bundle";
NSBundle *greeterBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
if(greeterBundle == nil){
    NSLog(@"Bundle not found at path");
}
else{
    //Dynamically load bundle
    NSError *error;
    BOOL isLoaded = [greeterBundle loadAndReturnError:&error];
    if(!isLoaded){
        NSLog(@"loading Error =%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else{
        //bundle loaded, create an object using bundle and send it a message
        Class GreeterClass = [greeterBundle classNamed:@"CustomGreeter"];

        id<Greeter> greeter = [[GreeterClass alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"%@", [greeter greeting:@"Hello"]);

        //Done with dynamically loaded bundle, now unload it
        //First release any objects whose class is defined in the bundle!
        greeter = nil;
        BOOL isUnloaded = [greeterBundle unload];
        if(!isUnloaded){
            NSLog(@"Couldn't unload bundle");
        }
    }
}
```